# How to setup RRAS as IPv6 Router and enable Router Advertisement

Tags: router, ipv6, rras

I have a Windows Server running on the local network acting as the router and VPN server. It has an IPv4 address with NAT enabled to provide internet access to devices on the network.
It also has a public IPv6 address `2001:470:ffff::1` with the subnet `2001:470:ffff::/48` assigned by the ISP. When I have DHCPv6 enabled, devices on the network are assigned an IPv6 address like `2001:470:ffff::1234` and can communicate with each other over IPv6. They are, however, not able to access the IPv6 internet due to the lack of default gateway.
On the windows clients, if I add the route `route add ::/0 2001:470:ffff::1`, they then have IPv6 internet access and can be reached from the internet.

If I disable DHCPv6, clients are not assigned an IPv6 address.

The problem seems to be that RRAS is not sending out Router Advertisement packets.

RRAS is configured as follows.

[image]

[image]

What is the correct way to setup RRAS as an IPv6 router?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that Windows is fully capable of acting as an IPv6 router and sending out Router Advertisement packets. However, it cannot be configured in the RRAS UI.

Two netsh commands are required.

```
netsh interface ipv6 set route 2001:470:ffff::/64 "Ethernet" publish=yes
netsh interface ipv6 set interface "Ethernet" advertise=enabled
```

The first command publishes 2001:470:ffff::/64 as the prefix for SLAAC.

The second command publishes the "Ethernet" interface and its link-local address as the default gateway in Router Advertisement packets. "Ethernet" is the network interface for the LAN port.